# Swift 3: iosMath label removing all spaces

Tags: replace, swift3, escaping, space

I'm trying to display text which may at times contain a math expression so I am using MTMathUILabel from iosMath. I generate the labels dynamically and add them to a stack as I pull the strings from the db. The problem is that all text which is not math appears with no spaces. i.e: 
In db: Solve the following equation: (math here)
In label: Solvethefollowingequation: (math here)

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
for question in all_questions {
    let finalString = question.question?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "\\space", options: .literal, range: nil)

    let label = MTMathUILabel()
    label.textColor = UIColor.black
    label.latex = finalString
    stack.addArrangedSubview(label)
}
```

But the problem is that it literally places two . And xcode doesn't let me write just one \ because it is not escaped. However if I just write

```
print("\\space")
```

Then it will print just one.

How can I fix this so I add only one \? If this cannot be done, how can I achieve what I want? Is there a better library out there?

Comment: Is the double backslash in your string after replacing spaces ?  or in the finalString variable (which you didn't indicate how it came to be) ? or in the displayed label ?   If your question string is properly formatted in LaTeX and not just some plain text, you shouldn't need to escape spaces.  Please provide more precision on where you see the problem occurring.

Comment: My bad, string and finalString are supposed to be the same variable. Not sure of what you're asking though. The string is properly formatted, I get it from a json object and then try to display it in the label, but the text appears without any spaces even though when I do a simple print it has spaces in it @AlainT.

Answer (score 0):

After giving a quick look at MTMathUILabel's doc and LaTeX conventions, I believe you should replace your spaces with a tilde character "~".  This will make them non-breaking spaces and avoid the backslash issue (which is probably due to \space not being understood by MTMathUILabel).

Systematic replacement of all spaces may yield undesirable result if the formula itself has legitimate spaces in it.

For example, a quadratic equation would be expressed as:

x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}

You will end up replacing spaces inside curly braces, and that may or may not be what you want:

x~=~\frac{-b~\pm~\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know if it works or not

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either :/. Regular text in the MTMathUILabel is still showing up without any spaces in it.

Comment: @Filipe did you get any solution yet ?

Comment: @Nitesh nope, switched mathjax